# Is there a way to make the parent component be skipped?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I'm new to angular and wanted to make a small project. I was making my routing when I hit a problem . I have this routing.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'home', component: LandingComponent},
    {path: 'menuitem', component: MenuItemComponent, children: [
        {path: 'create', component: MenuItemCreateComponent},
        {path: ':id', component: MenuItemDetailComponent}
    ]},
    {path: 'cart', component: CartComponent}
];
```

I wanted that 'menuitem' gets ignored and navigation goes straight to the children. Like if I want to load a specific id through 'menuitem/2', it would go load the menuitem with id = 2.

I was following a tutorial which used the parent path to display the list of items, but I forgot about it and had to review it to check how they did it there. What I did is `LandingComponent` is what displays, well, the landing page where I display everything that needs to be displayed at first run.

Is there a way to bypass the parent path? Right now, 'menuitem/:id' or 'menuitem/create' stops at `MenuItemComponent`.

The landing component html looks like this;

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div id="category-list">
        <app-category></app-category>
    </div>
    <div id="menu-item-list">
        <app-menu></app-menu>
    </div>
</div>
```

The one for menu item component html is the starting `<p>menu-item works!</p>`

Comment: Can you show the template for the MenuItemComponent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thinking, I think I found the best answer for my problem. As having a parent path makes things more complicated, I made the children paths from before just a regular path and it works just the way I wanted it to be. My routing looks like this now.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'home', component: LandingComponent},
    {path: 'menuitem/create', component: MenuItemCreateComponent},
    {path: 'menuitem/:id', component: MenuItemDetailComponent},
    {path: 'cart', component: CartComponent},
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove 'menuitem' from the path, there is no need to put path here

{path: '', component: MenuItemComponent, children: []

/////////////////
to organize your routes

const routes: Routes = [

```
{path: 'home', component: LandingComponent},

{path: '', component: MenuItemComponent, children: [
    {path: 'create', component: MenuItemCreateComponent},
    {path: ':id', component: MenuItemDetailComponent}
]},

{path: 'cart', component: CartComponent}
{ path: '', 
  redirectTo: '/home', 
  pathMatch: 'full'},
```

];

Comment: Wouldn't this make the path to create a menuitem /home/create? Which does really sit right for me. Or is that the only way ?

Comment: yes this will be the path /home/create